# Blur text in a Flow Document

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `FlowDocument` that I build up in code behind.  I need to be able to blur and unblur specific `Run`s and `Paragraph`s.

There is a `BlurEffect` but you can only apply it to `Controls`.  Runs and Blocks have a `TextEffect` property, but from what I can tell that is related to movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF has **BitmapEffects** which only can be set to Visual object. Paragraph and Run are derived from System.Windows.ContentElement, so we can not specify the BitmapEffects for them.

You can achieve blur effect like this

```
<FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.BitmapEffect>
                    <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="5"/>
                </TextBlock.BitmapEffect>
                <TextBlock.Inlines>
                    <Run Text="hello world" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="72" Foreground="Red" />
                </TextBlock.Inlines>
            </TextBlock>
        </InlineUIContainer>
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

result

[image]

---

update :using effects

```
 <FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Effect>
                    <BlurEffect Radius="30"/>
                </TextBlock.Effect>
                <TextBlock.Inlines>
                    <Run Text="hello world"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="72" Foreground="Red"/>
                </TextBlock.Inlines>
            </TextBlock>
        </InlineUIContainer>
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

Comment: hi thanks a lot this is a great start. Can the blur effect be strengthened to make the text virtually unreadable?

Comment: `BitmapEffect` is deprecated