# Blur flowdocument in WPF

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I'm looking a way to blur `FlowDocument` like this:

```
 FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
 BlurEffect blur = new BlurEffect();
 blur.Radius = 10;
 doc.Effect = blur; // it doesn't work! (FlowDocument doesn't have Effect property)
```

**Update:**

Above code is a part of a `Converter` which return `FlowDocument` for using in a `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`. Some items (returned flow documents) have specific conditions which should be blurred.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTemplateColumn>  
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>          
           <DataTemplate>
              <FlowDocumentScrollViewer 
                Document="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource ItemToFlowDocConverter}}"/>                
           </DataTemplate>  
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>       
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blur text in a Flow Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784051/blur-text-in-a-flow-document)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I want to blur 'FlowDocument' itself not containing items. I've updated my question.